# How to get current logged in user in Spring Cloud microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a `Spring Cloud` application with `Gateway` microservice powered with `Zuul`. `Gateway` main responsibility is to authenticate and authorize users with `Spring Security` and `JWT`.
Now in other microservices that are behind the `Gateway`, I want to get current logged in user. Any idea?

Comment: you can send it in the request header as correlationid and others

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a similar architecture. I achieved this in below way

Step 1 - Configure Zuul to pass headers to downstream systems by configuring sensitive headers in application properties.

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

Step 2 - Expose an endpoint in gateway that returns currently logged in user details

```
public UserReturnData fetchUserDetails() 
    {
        UserReturnData userReturnData = new UserReturnData();
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        userReturnData.setUsername(auth.getName());
        Long id=uRepo.findId(auth.getName());
        userReturnData.setId(id);
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        for (SimpleGrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
            roles.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        userReturnData.setRoles(roles);
        return userReturnData;
    }
```

Step 3 - From your micro-service, make API call (using resttemplate or web-client) to this exposed endpoint with bearer string in header.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService 
{
    @Autowired
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
    
    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;
    
    @Value("${common.serverurl}")
    private String reqUrl;
    
    public UserReturnData getCurrentUser()
    {
        UserReturnData userDetails = webClientBuilder.build()
                            .get()
                            .uri(reqUrl+"user/me")
                            .header("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization"))
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(UserReturnData.class)
                            .block();
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

This is if you want to keep it simple. If you have more complex requirements, you can use zuul filters.